# Practical way of expressing the $\delta$-function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-delta-distributions, density-of-states

I have got a problem in using the [$\delta$-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). As we know, this function is often used to define a 'density'-related quantity. Such as the density of states or some correlation function. Take the electronic density of states (DOS, $N(\epsilon)$) as an example, the DOS is defined as
$$N(\epsilon)={1\over N}\sum_{i}\delta(\epsilon-\epsilon_{i})$$ 
where $\epsilon$ is the energy, $N$ is the total number of electrons, the sum goes over all of the states of the electrons.

But in reality, when calculating the $N(\epsilon)$, we just divide the whole energy range into small steps with equal size. Then count the number of electrons whose energy lies in each small steps. After further scaling we can get the $N(\epsilon)$. I just want to know why is this holding.

I have ever saw some explanation of this treating in a QFT book. I says something like 
$\lim_{d\to 0}{N(\epsilon+d,\epsilon-d)\over N}$ can gives something like a $\delta$ function. But i can't remember the name of the book, nor can I find a similar formula. Can anybody give me some help on it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

Comment: Thanks for your link. I think this might be correlated with the correlation of Heaviside function and the $\delta function$. But I think in reality there should be some constraints on the length of the small step we have chosen. It should be small enough, but how small it should be.

Comment: What you are doing here falls squarely into the domain of functional analysis. You are really looking at the limits of functions as you were looking at the limits of numbers in ordinary analysis, so it's really about the convergence of sequences under some norm. From a physical perspective you can abstract from the mathematical convergence issues which are kicking off about three semesters worth of classes for mathematicians, just to get started with the basics. For most values the limit procedure has a finite value and the integral over divergences still has to be finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in reality, when calculating the $N(\epsilon)$, we just divide the whole energy range into small steps with equal size. Then count the number of electrons whose energy lies in each small steps. After further scaling we can get the $N(\epsilon)$. I just want to know why is this holding.

You are right. But then, if we want to know the number of electrons with energy *exactly* equal to $\epsilon$, we have to send the step size to zero. This means that we are defining

$$n(\epsilon) =  \sum_i \delta_{\epsilon, \epsilon_i}$$

and

$$N(\epsilon) = \frac 1 N  \sum_i \delta_{\epsilon, \epsilon_i}$$

where $\delta$ is the Kronecker-delta. But this expression is ok only if we are dealing with a discrete set of possible energies, $\{\epsilon_k\}$. If we are dealing with a continuous set, we have to make the substitution

$$\delta_{\epsilon, \epsilon_i} \to \delta(\epsilon-\epsilon_i)$$

The resulting expression

$$n(\epsilon) =  \sum_i \delta(\epsilon - \epsilon_i)$$

is really convenient, because we can easily integrate it to get the expected result:

$$\int n(\epsilon) d\epsilon =\sum_i \int \delta(\epsilon - \epsilon_i) d \epsilon= \sum_i 1 = N $$